# knitr adds an empty figure with ssplot from seqHMM package

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have the following chunk in RStudio:

```
<<sumfig,dependson='data',fig.cap="Summary of sequences">>=
ssplot(smult)
@
```

`ssplot` is a function in `seqHMM` package which creates a frequency graph and `smult` is my sequence data.

When I run my code, I get two figures in my pdf: The first one is an empty white figure with label `{fig:sumfig1}` and the second one is the real figure with label `{fig:sumfig1}`. I have similar experience with other plots from this package. I also have some other graphs in my file from other packages which work just fine.

Is it something wrong with the package or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of this issue seems to be `seqHMM:ssplot`, not `knitr`: Even in an interactive sesion, `ssplot` generates two plots, an empty one and the actual plot.

If there is only one plot generated in the chunk with `ssplot`, the [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) `fig.keep = "last"` can be used to disregard the first plot and show only the second (last) one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, fig.keep = "last">>=
library(seqHMM)

# from ?ssplot
data("biofam3c")

# Creating sequence objects
child_seq <- seqdef(biofam3c$children, start = 15)
marr_seq <- seqdef(biofam3c$married, start = 15)
left_seq <- seqdef(biofam3c$left, start = 15)

## Choosing colors
attr(child_seq, "cpal") <- c("#66C2A5", "#FC8D62")
attr(marr_seq, "cpal") <- c("#AB82FF", "#E6AB02", "#E7298A")
attr(left_seq, "cpal") <- c("#A6CEE3", "#E31A1C")


# Plotting state distribution plots of observations
ssplot(list("Children" = child_seq, "Marriage" = marr_seq,
            "Residence" = left_seq))
@

\end{document}
```

As of `knitr` [1.14](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md) (the current development version, available on [GitHub](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/README.md)), you can also use `fig.keep` to specify which plots exactly you want to keep: `fig.keep = c(1,3)` will keep the first and the third plot.

Comment: Yes, the issue is with the package. `fig.keep='last'` solves the problem. Is there any chunk option we can use to specify exactly which plots must be printed if we have more than two plots in the chunk?

Comment: According to the documentation on fig.keep, no. However, I think this could qualify for a useful feature request. I'll add a partial workaround tomorrow.

Comment: Update: Here is the [feature request](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1265).

Comment: @Milad Please check the updated answer; now you can selectively include figures.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful.